# Creating icons with gradient shadows

Tags: icon, gradient, shadows, gradient-mesh, minimalistic

I am attempting to create some animal icons in a particular style.

[image: Foxy Mark by Ivan Bobrov https://dribbble.com/shots/2859860-Foxy-mark]

What would your approach be in making an icon in a similar style? It looks to me like a lot of different gradients applied in different places, but I was wondering if any of you would take a different approach to it.

Comment: gradient doesn't have to be done with gradient tool. you can draw all objects in sepearate shapes with solid colors and then create new layers for shadows with brushes.

Comment: In Inkscape you can use the **[gradient mesh](http://goinkscape.com/how-to-unlock-the-gradient-mesh-tool-in-inkscape/)**.Have you tried it?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I did! That seemed to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very well! Are you able to write yourself an answer? It could be useful for the other people.